# How to separate rows into columns in SQL based on certain condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this:

```
Year    Q1      Q2      Q3      Q4
------------------------------------
2000    421     123     145     126
2000    422     124     146     127
2000    423     125     147     128
2000    424     126     148     129
2001    425     127     149     130
2001    426     128     150     131
2001    427     129     151     132
2002    428     130     152     133
2002    429     131     153     134
```

How do I get it like this:

```
Year    Q1      Q2      Q3      Q4      Year    Q1      Q2      Q3      Q4      Year    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2000    421     123     145     126     2001    425     127     149     130     2002    428 130 152 133
2000    422     124     146     127     2001    426     128     150     131     2002    429 131 153 134
2000    423     125     147     128     2001    427     129     151     132                 
2000    424     126     148     129
```

I visited this:https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/converting-rows-to-columns-pivot-and-columns-to-rows-unpivot-in-sql-server.html
but no success.
May I can do that with `PIVOT` But I am not been able to do that. Please suggest me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have an infinite number of years? I also **strongly** recommend against having columns of the same name.

Comment: No! I do not have infinite number of years.

Comment: May I know your purpose...this is not logical to set table like this.

Comment: how do you relate `Year 2000 Q1 421` with `Year 2001 Q1 425` ?

Comment: I want to convert rows into columns based on year condition.@Squirrel

Comment: there are multiple record with 2000 and 2001, how do you relate one to the other ?

Comment: @Squirrel For every year, there will be new column with values against those year.

Comment: why you place `Year 2000 Q1 421` with `Year 2001 Q1 425` on the same row and not `Year 2001 Q1 426` ?

Comment: You should not move how data should displayed into the database. Let the database do database stuff and let the view programm (excel, own prg, weppage) do the view/display stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ugly solution, in all honesty, and I don't really know why you'd want data to look like this. The `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause is a total guess, mind:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(2000,421,123,145,126),
                (2000,422,124,146,127),
                (2000,423,125,147,128),
                (2000,424,126,148,129),
                (2001,425,127,149,130),
                (2001,426,128,150,131),
                (2001,427,129,151,132),
                (2002,428,130,152,133),
                (2002,429,131,153,134)) V ([Year], Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)),
RNs AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year] ORDER BY Q1) AS RN --ORDER BY is total guess
    FROM VTE)
SELECT RN1.[Year], RN1.Q1, RN1.Q2, RN1.Q3, RN1.Q4,
       RN2.[Year], RN2.Q1, RN2.Q2, RN2.Q3, RN2.Q4,
       RN3.[Year], RN3.Q1, RN3.Q2, RN3.Q3, RN3.Q4
FROM RNs RN1
     LEFT JOIN RNs RN2 ON RN1.[Year] = RN2.[Year] - 1
                      AND RN1.RN = RN2.RN
     LEFT JOIN RNs RN3 ON RN1.[Year] = RN3.[Year] - 2
                      AND RN1.RN = RN3.RN
WHERE RN1.[Year] = (SELECT MIN(sq.[Year])
                    FROM RNs sq)
ORDER BY RN1.RN;
```

This will also not work as intended if a year after the lowest has more rows that the first one (for example, if 2003 had 5 rows, you would only get 4). This could be handled, if really needed.

Edit: IT's still ugly, but this helps when you have more row later on:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(2000,421,123,145,126),
                (2000,422,124,146,127),
                (2000,423,125,147,128),
                (2000,424,126,148,129),
                (2001,425,127,149,130),
                (2001,426,128,150,131),
                (2001,427,129,151,132),
                (2002,428,130,152,133),
                (2002,429,131,153,134),
                (2003,429,132,154,135),
                (2003,430,133,155,136),
                (2003,431,134,156,137),
                (2003,432,135,157,138),
                (2003,433,136,158,139)) V ([Year], Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)),
RNs AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year] ORDER BY Q1) AS RN --ORDER BY is total guess
    FROM VTE),
Tally AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT RNs.RN, Y.MinYear
    FROM RNs
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(Year) AS MinYear FROM RNs) Y)
SELECT RN1.[Year], RN1.Q1, RN1.Q2, RN1.Q3, RN1.Q4,
       RN2.[Year], RN2.Q1, RN2.Q2, RN2.Q3, RN2.Q4,
       RN3.[Year], RN3.Q1, RN3.Q2, RN3.Q3, RN3.Q4,
       RN4.[Year], RN4.Q1, RN4.Q2, RN4.Q3, RN4.Q4
FROM Tally T
     LEFT JOIN RNs RN1 ON T.RN = RN1.RN
                      AND RN1.[Year] = T.MinYear
     LEFT JOIN RNs RN2 ON T.MinYear = RN2.[Year] - 1
                      AND T.RN = RN2.RN
     LEFT JOIN RNs RN3 ON T.MinYear = RN3.[Year] - 2
                      AND T.RN = RN3.RN
     LEFT JOIN RNs RN4 ON T.MinYear = RN4.[Year] - 3
                      AND T.RN = RN4.RN
ORDER BY T.RN;
```

Comment: In case if 2003 has 5 rows, how would I handle in future? Any Idea

Comment: @Dungeon I've added something else for you.

Comment: When I run this by adding one row of year say `2004` It is not displaying in the ouput result.@Larnu

Comment: Did you add the extra `JOIN`? you have to have a `LEFT JOIN` for **every** year. This is why the solution is ugly and why I don't understand why you want the solution you had. I **assumed** that you had a finite number of years (based on your comment under your question), however, this seems to be becoming less of the case if you're now doing 2000 - 2004. will you have 2000 - 2018, will 2019 and 2020 start appearing too? if so, this query is going to become awful...

Comment: I got it.One last help, though I do not have infinite year but for every year I have to do extra join. Any other way possible? I still appreciate your answer.@Larnu

Comment: @Dungeon Yes, change your data model. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174933/discussion-between-dungeon-and-larnu).